# PHP Switch Pays Attention to Capitalization?

Tags: php

I've pulled a string out into an array and am looping through it with a PHP switch. My only problem is that I need my switch to be sensitive to capital letters.

Here's an example string:

```
$string = "AAaa BBbb CCcc DDDD"
```

After exploding you get something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => AAaa [1] => BBbb [2] => CCcc [3] => DDDD )
```

My switch needs to find multiple things in the array and return a different result based on what it finds. For example:

```
switch (true) {
    case ($array[0]='AAaa'):
        echo "There is an AAaa";
        break;
    case (($array[0]='AAaa') && ($array[3]='DDDD')):
            echo "AAaa and DDDD are both there";
            break;
    default:
            echo "Nothing is there! ):";
 }
```

It works well when you're looking for different letters, but sometimes my string will have "aaaa", "AAAA", etc. and I need my switch to be able to tell the difference.

I know this can be done with if-elseif-else statements, but switches are a lot easier to read, in my opinion.

Comment: Switches _are not_ easier to read.

Comment: You are using assignment operators instead of comparison operators.

Comment: http://codepad.org/BVZIjWMf

Comment: Comparision of string with `==` operator is case sensitive

Comment: Depending on what you're actually trying to do, you might want to look into [in_array](http://php.net/in_array), which is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are are using `=` instead of `==` for comparison

Replace:

```
($array[0]='AAaa')
```

with:

```
($array[0]=='AAaa')
```